# Detect stepper motor movement using a Hall Effect sensor

Tags: stepper-motor, hall-effect

Is it possible to detect that a stepper motor is rotating using a Hall sensor against its body? Kind of a simple detection mechanism for motor stall without moving parts.

EDIT: I want to make sure the motor is physically rotating without adding more stuff to the mechanical side.

Comment: The stepper motor is a cheap solution, because it doesn't have feedback. It doesn't make sense to add a feedback and cost, since it won't have such performance as BLDC/PMSM for the same price.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know if someone in the community has some experience or tips about this.

Comment: @PedroNF why the hall sensor? doesn't measuring current give you essentially the same info, but requiring a 2 ct shunt resistor instead of a hall effect sensor?

Comment: @Markus The motor is controller by a PLC with its stepper controller, just looking for a simple inexpensive external solution, to plug into an input pin of the PLC.

Comment: You'd do better using a hall current sensor on a motor *lead*

Comment: @ChrisStratton Will it work if the motor gets physically blocked and is loosing steps? The controller will be sending the signals so I guess they will be detected as if the motor is turning, even if its physically blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I've experimented with placing GMR angle sensors outside the housing of a single pole-pair BLDC inrunner motor to try and measure the commutation angle directly from the rotor magnet. With a lookup table, I was able to recover enough of a signal to get the motor to spin, but very inefficiently. The housing and field lines produced in the stator distorted and interfered with the signal significantly.

Could you, in theory, get a magnetic field sensor to work outside a stepper motor as a crude rotor position sensor? Probably. Will it work well? Probably not. It depends strongly on the motor and sensor you're using, and making sense of the signal you (may or may not) get would be difficult, and would likely be totally different if you tried to repeat the setup.

It's pretty easy to test for yourself, I recommend just getting a linear hall effect or TMR sensor, throw the output voltage(s) on an oscilloscope, and see if you can make sense of the result. It's a fun thing to try.

Comment: I have two motors on each side of a plate and I need to make sure that none of them will block or lose steps, otherwise plate is no longer horizontal and the stuff in the plate will fall. Its a simple R&D machine so I'm looking for a simple solution. Your answer encourages me to make a test with a magnetic sensor ;-)